# Using Sikuli4Net in selenium c# and getting a (403) forbidden

Tags: c#, selenium, canvas, sikuli

Before I begin, I'd like to say that if anybody thinks I'm on the wrong path, I'm open to trying different suggestions within my selenium framework. I've been happily developing my selenium test suit (c#, Nunit) in for quite some time now and unfortunately come up against something quite frustrating when trying to implement Sikuli4Net.

My project needed to introduce a canvas to graphically draw a data flow diagram and interact with it, but this has the added complexity of not having any of the usual stuff selenium uses to identify objects on a screen. I've been to a few forums and they all seem to suggest using Sikuli4Net to interact with it graphically.

I started off by following a few YouTube videos but i can't seem to get anything to work. every time i run my test i get the following stack trace:

```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
      at Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST.Screen.MakeRequest(String requestURLExtension, String jsonObject)
      at Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST.Screen.Click(Pattern pattern, KeyModifier kmod, Boolean highlight)
      at Builder2018.SmokeTests.canvas.canvasBob(String BrowserName, String Environment, String System) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Builder2018\Builder2018\Builder2018\SmokeTests\canvas.cs:line 38
   Result Message:  System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

I've temporarily given up on attempting to implement it against my actual project and am just trying to get a hello world type example going using Google but still get the above error. is there something simple I'm missing because it shouldn't be this hard...

As far as I'm aware, I've done all necessary configuration (JDK, environment variables, etc), Here is my current attempt at implementing it:

```
 namespace AutomationStuffs.SmokeTests
 {
     [TestFixture]
     public class canvas : TestBase
     {
         APILauncher launcher = new APILauncher();
         [Test]
         [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestBase), "TestData")]
         public void canvasBob(String BrowserName, String Environment, String System)
         {
             //Start API Launcher
            launcher.Start();
            //Configure test setup - within my environment i would usually perform a repeated login step here within setup
             Setup(BrowserName, Environment, System, new string[] { });
            //GoTo Google
             KnowledgeBasePage.GoToGoogle();
            //Test steps i have issue with
                Screen screenGoogle = new Screen();
                Pattern element1 = new Pattern(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\AutomationStuffs\AutomationStuffs\PageImages\feelinglucky.PNG");
                screenGoogle.Click(element1);
             //Start API Launcher
            launcher.Stop();
         }
     }
 }
```

---

Just for completeness - I've included the other appropriate bits that get called:

```
  public void Setup(String BrowserName, String Environment, String System, String[] Additional)
  {
      //launcher.Start();
      Driver.Intialize(BrowserName);
    //perform SQL inserts and set appropriate data based on BrowserName, Environment, System, Additional..
      //LoginSteps(); //not used for this example test
  }
```

---

```
 public static void Intialize(String BrowserName)
 {
     String DRIVER_PATH = chromeDriver;
     String DRIVER_PATH_IEFF = ieDriver;
     String DRIVER_PATH_EDGE = edgeDriver;
     var optionsChrome = new ChromeOptions();
     optionsChrome.AddArgument("start-maximized");
     optionsChrome.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
     var opt = new FirefoxOptions
     {
         BrowserExecutableLocation = @"c:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe"
     };
     //var driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
     var optionsIe = new InternetExplorerOptions();

     if (BrowserName.Equals("ie"))
     {
         Instance = new InternetExplorerDriver(DRIVER_PATH_IEFF);
         Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
     }
     else if (BrowserName.Equals("firefox"))
     {
         Instance = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
         Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
         Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
     }
     else if (BrowserName.Equals("edge"))
     {
         Instance = new EdgeDriver(DRIVER_PATH_EDGE);
         Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
     }
     else if (BrowserName.Equals("chrome"))
     {
         Instance = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH, optionsChrome);
         Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
     }
     else
     {
         //Your test has failed because an unsupported browser-name was selected!
         Assert.Fail("Your test has failed because an unsupported browser-name was selected! Currently supported browser names in the BrowsersList.resx file are: ie,firefox,edge,chrome - these are Case sensitive");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought I would drop some info on where I got to with this. Basically, I switched up and used SikuliIntegrator instead.

The code is much easier and no API launcher. I was able to refactor my code easier and separate the actual code doing the action from my tests, leaving them human readable. The only downside is the wait time while it starts up, it's adding about 2 to 7 seconds on to the tests. The test and code I've used looks as follows:

```
        namespace AutomationStuffs.SmokeTests
        {
            [TestFixture]
            public class canvas : TestBase
            {
                [Test]
                [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestBase), "TestData")]
                public void canvasBob(String BrowserName, String Environment, String System)
                {
                    //Configure test setup - within my environment i would usually perform a repeated login step here within setup
                    Setup(BrowserName, Environment, System, new string[] { });
                    //GoTo Google
                    KnowledgeBasePage.GoToGoogle();
                    GooglePage.ClickImFeelingLucky();
                    Assert.IsTrue(googlePage.OnTheImFeelingLuckyPage());
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
    public static void ClickImFeelingLucky()
    {
        Wait.WaitForPageElementToBeVisible(By.Name("q"), 10);
        string MyPicture = @"C:\..\intractionImages\Capture.PNG";
        Console.WriteLine(MyPicture);
        SikuliAction.Click(MyPicture);
        Wait.WaitForPageElementToBeVisible(By.Id("lang-chooser"), 10);
    }
```

Found all useful information here https://qaagent.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/how-to-use-sikuli-in-my-c-coded-tests/

Here is the meat of the article:

Make sure Java is configured properly:
REQUIREMENTS

- java 1.6 – tested with jre-6u35-windows-i586.exe
- Microsoft .NET 4.5
- NuGet

> ```
> Add JAVA_HOME environment variable with value = path to installed JRE bin folder.
> ```

INSTALLATION
You can get a StartUp project,  or can create a new project by following the next steps:

1. Create new project in Visual Studio 2012
2. In the “Solution Explorer” – right-click on the solution
3. Choose  “Manage NuGet Packages for Solution…”
4. Search for “SikuliIntegrator” and install it
5. After the installation “JSikuliModule.jar” should be part of your solution, together with some additional files
6. Right-Click on “JSikuliModule.jar” and choose “Properties”
7. Set “Copy to Output Directory” property to “Copy always”

I found step 6 and 7 to be the most important part of this whole thing

Here is a list of additional reading i did that i found usefull:

- http://interviews.ga/angularjs/sikuli/
- [Sikuli Integrator C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837423/sikuli-integrator-c-sharp)
- https://github.com/christianrondeau/SikuliSharp
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sikuli-using-selenium-in-c-sharp
- http://nadimsaker.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/sikuli-how-to-install-and-run-sikuli-in.html