# Moving mouse pointer(cursor) to a specific location or element using C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I performing a click operation using Selenium and C#.

I can able to perform click operation but i can't able to move mouse pointer(cursor) to a specific co-ordinate or over specific element.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveByOffset(500, 500).ContextClick().Perform();
```

This is the code I am using. The context click is working but the cursor not moving.

Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to get an element just move by offset. Make sure you know what your prior focus is... If none then it should be the top left corner of the page. Then put your sleep in the middle and you should be able to see the mouse move, wait, and then click.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveByOffset(200,100).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
action.Click();
```

Comment: Click action is being performed. What i need is to move the mouse pointer(arrow).

Comment: Selnium doesn't uses actual cursor movements to perform click. You will have to use some other library to move mouse cursor and perform click. Please care to explain why do you need cursor to  be actually moved? Any specific thing you want to achieve?

Comment: Just for the animation and presentation purpose, i was in need of cursor movement.

Comment: @KrishnaSahu You need to use Sikuli library if you want to move the mouse pointer to one point to other.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066138/sikuli-integration-with-selenium-error-for-wait-condition

Comment: @Dhru'soni It's a Java library. I am using C#.Net.

Comment: @KrishnaSahu you can use sikuli in C# .. Refer this link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837423/sikuli-integrator-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks @Dhru'soni. I will try it.