# Sikuli integration with selenium error for wait condition

Tags: java, selenium, sikuli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYy7H.png)

screen.wait(username, 10);

I'm having an error message like at `org.sikuli.script.Region.wait` and how can I run Sikuli integration with *selenium projects* in **command prompt** even I have added required Sikuli jar - while running in command prompt I'm getting as Sikuli package missing.

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern fileUpload = new Pattern("a.PNG");
Pattern fileSelect = new Pattern("b.PNG");
Pattern AWBSelect = new Pattern("c.PNG");
Pattern AWBupload = new Pattern("d.PNG");
Pattern AWBSearch = new Pattern("e.PNG");

screen.wait(fileUpload, 10);
screen.click(fileUpload);
screen.wait(fileSelect, 10);
screen.click(fileSelect);
screen.type("a", KeyModifier.CTRL);
screen.type(Key.BACKSPACE,"C:\\Users\\PoojaPatange\\eclipse-workspacepractice\\CIToolAutomationRegression\\lib");
screen.type(Key.ENTER);
screen.wait(AWBSelect, 10);
screen.click(AWBSelect);
screen.wait(AWBupload, 10); 
screen.click(AWBupload);
screen.wait(AWBSearch, 10); 
screen.click(AWBSearch);
```

Comment: did you get any "FindFailed: cannot find" error above the org.sikuli.script.Region.wait. Please post your complete java code and error stack trace.

Comment: Hi @Dhru'soni , I have added my code and screenshot please check and yes I have findfailed issue.

Comment: that means your images not exactly match with your data whatever you use like button search window. Recheck and try with exact images.

Comment: if solution work please upvote and mark as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an exact path of an image like below code. Here I tested for google page for searching contents and click on google search button.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class DemoWindowBasedApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {

        Screen screen = new Screen();
        Pattern image = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\test\\Videos\\snspshot\\october\\12\\google.png");
        Pattern image1 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\test\\Videos\\snspshot\\october\\12\\testGoogle.png");
        Pattern googleSearch = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\test\\Videos\\snspshot\\october\\12\\googleSearch.png");
        Pattern closeBrowser = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\test\\Videos\\snspshot\\october\\12\\close.png");

        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "D:\\Automation\\Drivers_Automation\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        screen.click(image);
        screen.type(image1,"Software testing");
        screen.click(googleSearch);
        screen.click(closeBrowser);
        screen.wait(image, 10);

    }
}
```

I attached sample images how you can take a snapshot and match exactly while running sikuli program

[image: Googlesearch]
[image: testGoogle]

Comment: screen.wait(10);                                                        java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException                                                                                            Im getting above exception  can i use wait condition like above ?

Comment: @PoojaPatange to get Sikuli's wait() method (the signature wait(long value) (e.g. s.wait(1) is occupied by JavaObject) use this  screen.wait(double value) (e.g. screen.wait(10.0) )

Comment: thank you for suggestion, can you please help me to run above code in command prompt. Im getting error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sikuli/script/Screen and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sikuli.script.Screen